# Add a toggle for disabling diff markup when reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, diff

I review suggested edits on Stack Overflow that contain lots of alterations to back-tick code tags. It can be quite difficult to get a feel for how the edited post *looks* once those changes have been made.

If I use the "rendered output" page, the coloured diff markup can confuse matters. If I use the "markdown" page, you lose the ability to judge whether the edit looks pleasant.

I would propose the diff colouration becomes a toggle-able feature, as suggested in the image below. When the toggle is unchecked, the colouration will vanish, thus showing the real rendering of the edit.

[image: toggle example]

I see no reason this preference should be stored on a per-user basis - I would be happy for it to default to being checked every time the dialog is opened.

I also believe this would have benefits beyond my back-tick example above - other formatting requires one to really look at the finished product. After all - why do we show the original editor the review pane?